# Should we fix the Guardians of the Galaxy tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently noticed that we have these tags for Guardians of the Galaxy:

- [guardians-of-the-galaxy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy) for the series of films about the titular Guardians,
- [guardians-of-the-galaxy-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-1) for the first film, 'Guardians of the Galaxy',
- [guardians-of-the-galaxy-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-2) for the second film, 'Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 2'

The first one I'm fine with, but the second two bother me for a couple reasons:

- in the past (say, with Thor, Iron Man, and Ant-Man), when the first film in the series is named after the titular character, the film-tag has been the name of the film along with the year (see [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9682/46611))
- we have no guarantee that the next film will be 'Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 3'; in fact, since Peter never got a third Awesome Mix, such a title wouldn't make much sense. Plus, while the first film is sometimes referred to as 'Vol. 1', that change doesn't seem to be official.

Thus, I propose the film tags to be renamed to the following:

- [guardians-of-the-galaxy-2014](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-2014) for the first film
- [guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol2) for the second film

Comment: I've added this case to [Thunderforge's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296669/348200) on main meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The rename you propose is impossible.** The current tag names are already *exactly* at the 25-character limit, so if you want to make the last part longer than a single character, you'll have to compensate by shortening the rest of the tag name, e.g. [guardians-galaxy-2014](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-galaxy-2014) or [gotg-2014](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gotg-2014). Personally I think [guardians-of-the-galaxy-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-1) looks better than either of these, given that the tag wiki excerpt is clear, but I'm not into Marvel/DC stuff, so I'm open to persuasion from those who are.

In fact, this very issue was already [discussed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=35994081#35994081) during the big retagging event:

> *CreationEdge*: @Randal'Thor can you rename [guardians-of-the-galaxy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy) to [guardians-of-the-galaxy-2014](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-2014). I double-checked and all questions are about the movie.
>   *Randal'Thor*: @CreationEdge No, I can't. That breaks the character limit for tags.
>   *CreationEdge*: dang, was worried about that. [guardians-of-the-galaxy-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-1) then?
>   *Randal'Thor*: Done. Add [guardians-of-the-galaxy-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-1) to your list of tag wikis to rewrite once this is over.

Comment: Ah. Well, that's too bad. But definitely not the first time bad names have been used because of character limitations.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh [Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209248/278659) a [couple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197889/278659) of feature requests you may want to upvote, if you haven't already.